# Not able to implement DataTable cucumber feature in QAF

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd, qaf

I am trying to get the vales as DataTable in cucumber. How can this be done in QAF ?

```
   @test
      Scenario: DataTable Examples
        Given I am on github login page
        And I enter usernames and passwords "${args[0]}"
          | testuser_1 | Test@153 |
```

```
StepDefinition

  @And("^I enter usernames and passwords \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void iEnterUsernamesAndPasswords(Map<Object, Object> data) {
        System.out.println("------------->" +data.get(0));
    }
```

Error Msg:

```
[WINDOWS  91.0.4472.77]: ▀ ▀ ▀ END STEP: Given I am on github login page ▀ ▀ ▀
17:28:22.608 [[WINDOWS  91.0.4472.77]] ERROR com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.StepNotFoundException - 
/**
* Auto-generated code snippet by QMetry Automation Framework.
*/
@QAFTestStep(description="I enter usernames and passwords {0}{1}")
public void iEnterUsernamesAndPasswords(String str0,Object[] objArray1){
    //TODO: remove NotYetImplementedException and call test steps
    throw new NotYetImplementedException();
}

/**
* Auto-generated code snippet by QMetry Automation Framework.
*/
@QAFTestStep(description="I enter usernames and passwords {0}{1}")
public void iEnterUsernamesAndPasswords(String str0,Object[] objArray1){
    //TODO: remove NotYetImplementedException and call test steps
    throw new NotYetImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`args[0]` is used when you have data-driven scenario (scenario with examples) and you want to refer entire record from data provider. In this case as you want to pass map you can try following way:

```
@test
      Scenario: DataTable Examples
        Given I am on github login page
        And I enter usernames and passwords "{'username':'testuser_1', 'password':'Test@153'}"
```

Or

```
@test
      Scenario: DataTable Examples
        Given I am on github login page
        And I enter usernames and passwords 
          | username | password |
          | testuser_1 | Test@153 |
```

You can refer [feature files](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/tree/master/test/resources/features) and [step implementation](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/tree/master/test/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/impl/step).